# xcodebuild -create-framework error: unable to read the file

Tags: swift, xcodebuild

I have watched "binary framework in swift" and tried to build xcframework using xcodebuild -create-framework but it is not working properly.

I enabled "Build libraries for Distribution", then I archived and then used the command 
`xcodebuild -create-framework -framework /path/sample.xarchive -output sample.xcframework`

But it is showing an error "unable to read the file at /path/sample/sample". 
I am not sure what I am missing.

Sysytem Info:

MacOS: Catalina beta 1

Xcode 11

Answer (score 17):

Here are step by step instructions, I think you might be missing step 2:

1) Set `Build Library for Distribution` in the build settings for the target framework to `YES`

2) Again in the build settings, set `Skip Install` to `NO` otherwise the framework won't show up in the Archive output folder.

3) Archive from the Xcode Product menu after selecting your `Generic iOS Device` the output will appear in the Organizer. Control-Click on the Archive. Select `Show in Finder` Drag that to the terminal to get the path to the archive and append the path (yellow part is the dragged path, gray is navigated in subfolders). In this case it looks like this, I used the ~ to avoid showing entire path.

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-06-22/Output\ 6-22-19,\ 11.50\ AM.xcarchive/`Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework`

4) Then create the XCFramework by inserting the command in front of the above path:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -output Output.xcframework -framework ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-06-22/Output\ 6-22-19,\ 11.50\ AM.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework
```

5) You then should see the output:

```
xcframework successfully written out to: ~/Project/Output.xcframework
```

I expect that someday soon Xcode will add a the ability to directly create the XCFramework without the command line.

Comment: Mistake I made was putting the path to the .xcarchive file instead of the .framework file contained within the archive.

Comment: Is it possible that `Build Libraries for Distribution` has to be set in the project settings and cannot be used as an argument for `xcodebuild`? I've seen folks mentioning to use `BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES` but it never works for me. I HAVE to set it in the project settings

Comment: Take a note that "Build Library for Distribution" option is only available in Xcode 11.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a two step process via the command line.

1. xcodebuild archive

This will archive the framework and stick it likely in the build directory of your project.

2. xcodebuild -create-xcframework -output FrameworkName.xcframework -framework build/Release-iphoneos/ArchivedFramework.framework

This should successfully generate the XCFramework.

Answer (score 0):

You typed the command wrong:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework /path/sample.xarchive -output sample.xcframework
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was failing for iPhone as arm64 architecture was added in the `Excluded Architecture` in Build Settings